# Woocommerce single product - template by categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Already posted question but not working for me, so I'm asking a little help guys... ;)

There is my **single-product.php (woocommerce file line:28)**

```
 <?php if ( is_product_category( 'customcateg' ) ) 
    {
       woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-customcateg' ); }
else {      
       woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); } 
  ?>
```

I have in my theme/woocommerce 3 files:

- single-product.php
- content-single-product.php
- content-single-product-customcateg.php

The files contains different php codes (the customcateg has to be protected from visitors, and some roles; this part is already done...)

When i try to access a product who is in "customcateg", it shows me the normal "single-product" template....

I tried to put :

```
 <?php if ( is_product_category( 'customcateg' ) ) 
    {
       woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-customcateg' ); }
else {      
       woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-customcateg' ); } 
  ?>
```

It simply show the single-product, but it has to show the customcateg one, but it does not. It only does when I pust the "single-product-customcateg.php" content in the "single-product.php" ...

What's wrong guys ?

Please help me :)

Thanks a lot by advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking for a file titled content-single-product-customcateg.php

That file doesn't exist so it's falling back to the default.

```
if ( has_term( 'customcateg', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-customcateg' );
} else {
    woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
}
```

Can you add the contents of your content-single-product-customcateg.php by the way?

Comment: You are true, I made a mistake, my files are :

single-product.php
content-single-product.php
content-single-product-customcateg.php

(my bad...)

Comment: Can you clarify; did that fix the problem or was the mistake in your post and you're still having a problem?

Comment: I made a mistake while asking, I still have the problem... Thanks

Comment: Can you include a larger snippet from single-product.php to put your code into context? The second loop you posted is redundant by the way. The outcome of the loop is always going to be the same.

Comment: It's normal about the redundant (was just for trying if the template was loading, but it's not... :(

Comment: Here you go for a larger snippet : 
`<?php
/**
* woocommerce_before_main_content hook
* @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
* @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
*/
do_action('woocommerce_before_main_content');
?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
if ( is_product_category( 'edition' ) ) {
woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-edition' ); }
else {  
woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); } ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>`

Comment: And to confirm you're viewing a single product? If so is_product_category will fail. It returns true when you're viewing the category page and not when a product is in that category.

Comment: Yes I understand what you're meaning. But how I do if I want to use a custom product template on products pages of a specific category ? This is my problem... Thanks for your support

(I need to do this for lock by php this products for some roles)

Comment: There is my content-single-product-customcateg.php content :
http://pastebin.com/xFKgUFSw

About the "if (has_term...." it's not working too. Just displaying the default, don't know why... :(

Comment: OK in that case single-product.php isn't the file being used so your code isn't firing. To confirm delete the conditional so no template part is called and see if the default is still shown.

Comment: Yes I confirm that no template file is called... This is so strange because when I modify (mytheme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php) it shows the modification, even the conditional removed.

Comment: No clue about how to fix it :(

Comment: When you deleted the conditional entirely none was shown, correct? This is in single-product.php and not content-single-product.php as well right?

Comment: When I completely delete the conditional, it loads... It's like if the "single-product.php" page was not used..... :(

Comment: You're spot on. That's exactly what's happening. Without going into much more detail on your project I wouldn't be able to tell you why.

Comment: I just sent you a mail, in this way we could chat easily... Thanks