# WooCommerce custom theme by category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create specific Woo templates for product categories in WooCommerce.

I've tried to follow the instructions here but they didn't work for me. [Woocommerce single product - template by categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501746/woocommerce-single-product-template-by-categories)

I also found this but couldn't get it to work. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-woocommerce-excelling-ecommerce-a-custom-single-product-template

In my theme I have a woocommerce folder with the specific template files that I want to override.

```
theme/woocommerce/single-product.php
theme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php
theme/woocommerce/content-single-product-custom-1.php
```

here is part of single-product.php

```
<?php if (is_product_category( 'custom-1')) {
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-custom-1' );
    }
    elseif (is_product_category( 'promise') {
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-custom-2' );
    }
    else{
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
    } 
?>
```

I have the custom-1 category setup in woo on the specific product I want to target.

When I edit content-single-product-custom-1.php nothing changes. However when I make changes to content-single-product.php they are show up.

Why am I not able to target the my product categories?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the fact that [is_product_category()](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/) behaves the same as [is_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) or [is_tax()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) Wordpress functions, which means that it checks if a category archive page ( in this case a custom taxonomy archive page ) is being displayed. And you are in single post page, you can use functions like [has_term()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) ( to check if the current post has any of the given terms ) or [get_the_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) ( to retrieve the terms of the taxonomy that are attached to the post ), in WooCommeerce the taxonomy is **'product_cat'**.

---

```
<?php 
    if ( has_term( 'custom-1', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-custom-1' );
    } elseif ( has_term( 'promise', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-custom-2' );
    } else {
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
    } 
?>
```

Comment: I tried your code but it still isn't working... Would it be possible that I'm not adding taxonomy terms properly? I've tried adding the "custom-1" as a category in woo and I've tried adding it as a tag, still nothing. Would it be possible to target my custom theme via a post id number?

Comment: So, I'm just trying to get a better grasp of everything... So, wooCommerce adds the taxonomy term 'product_cat' and the other term is based off the category term.

Comment: Try to use `print_r( get_the_terms( $post->id, 'product_cat' ) );` if you are outside the loop, or `print_r( get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' ) );` inside the loop ( all in 'single-product.php' template ), to see if the terms of the 'product_cat' taxonomy are attached to product correctly. If you don't get any output then you doing it wrong.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because I'm not getting any output. Here is what I have in single-product.php [PasteBin - single-product.php](http://pastebin.com/p9ZWmKjd) I changed the second category name by the way. Is there anything else that I could paste in that would help you see the problem? I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: You removed the whole loop, try now http://pastebin.com/vHLkP79d . If you are still not getting any output then template is not even loaded

Comment: I'm still not getting any output! How can I get the template to load? Thanks so much for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only guess where the problem is. Try to start  from the beginning, visit Woo documentation to see how to properly override templates and how to create products and categories. Check your progress at every step, and you will eventually succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your functions.php file toinclude the product_cat_CATEGORYNAME term in your products body class.

```
function woo_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class( $classes ){
if( is_singular( 'product' ) )
{
    $custom_terms = get_the_terms(0, 'product_cat');
    if ($custom_terms) {
        foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
            $classes[] = 'product_cat_' . $custom_term->slug;
        }
    }
}
return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'woo_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class' );
```

The product_cat term can now be referenced